# How do I ping a website to see if its valid before entering?

Tags: javascript, url, roblox

So I am just making a basic html page to find a random subsite(?) in the roblox domain. When trying to fetch the site, it shows a redirect error even though loading it manually doesn't. So now I want to try to open the site with inserted code or something automatically then close it if it actually is a running subsite(?)

this is the js code I currently have (everything)

```
const connect = document.getElementById("connection");
var idsel = document.getElementById("gameid");


function findRandom()
{
    let sel = Math.round(Math.random()*99999999);
    let url = "https://www.roblox.com/games/"+sel+"/";
    connect.setAttribute("href",url);
    idsel.textContent = "Game: "+url;
    

}
```

but sometimes it loads in `https://www.roblox.com/request-error?code=404` because the game doesnt exist. So instead of reloading every time until it's an actual working game, I want it to try, check the url after loading or ping it before hand, repeat until its a working url. I also want to remove specific games by checking the url or ping it.

Comment: I don't think there's any way to do this.

Comment: there was, i deleted *my* answer though, you can just use `fetch(url,{mode:"no-cors"})`.

it turned out it was a cors issue with pinging. nothing else.

Comment: ping isn't related to HTTP requests. You can use a HEAD HTTP method request rather than a full GET to check if a url exists

Comment: @clownfish That's just not the case if you don't own the domain. No-Cors mode is opaque and won't even tell you if a page exists. There is nothing you can learn from an external domain with such a request apart from the fact that CORS headers aren't or are present.

Comment: @OneCricketeer I think they were using "ping" as a generic term for sending a message that tests whether a site is alive, not referring to the `ping` command. There's even a utility called `http-ping`.